# how to store a part of dropdownlist text in a dynamically generated property

Tags: c#, asp.net

here is my code:

```
EntityLayer.Entity[] en = new EntityLayer.Entity[counter];
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected == true)
    {
        en[count] = new EntityLayer.Entity();
        en[count].all_Emp_Mobile = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        en[count].all_Emp_Name = DropDownList1.Text;
        en[count].all_Stu_Mobile = CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Value.ToString();
        count++;
    }
}
```

now the thing is that the dropdown list text has both the name and mobile number concatenated and seperated by **"/"** character. what i want to do is to just save the name of the person in the property `en[count].all_Emp_Name`., is there a method in c# like `Remove` or something like that which can remove the the latter part i.e the mobile number from the string.

`Remove` method demands the index from where you want to remove the text and for that i might use
`Indexof` but i am a little confused here how to go about it, as the property is generated dynamically in the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do something like this:

```
string DropDownText = "EhsanSajjad/03123009099";

string[] temp = DropDownText.Split('/');

string personName  = temp[0];

string CellNumber = temp[1];
```

Comment: Although i didnt wanted to use split method but it seems like  i could work this way the only thing is that there has been another problem in the code that is as soon as there is a post back on the page
the text part of the drop downlist which otherwise would contain both name and mobile no.now only has mobile number to it.

Comment: i tested your way its also working fine :) 
the only thing is if a user happened to insert two or  more '/' characters in the name part. then `LastIndexOf`method works fine together with `Remove`. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

got it finally....

```
 int index = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.LastIndexOf('/');
 string empName = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Remove(index);
 en[count].all_Emp_Name = empName;
```

this seems to be working just perfect.

Comment: Good brother 1 up from me